# Ubuntu not connecting to wifi network

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 today. This is a PC and since motherboard doesn't have inbuilt wifi I attached a PCI Wifi Card.

When I installed Ubuntu it automatically detected the wifi card. it shows me all available networks.

But when I click on my network. It shows me a circle for 1 minute and then the circle disappears and it doesn't connect to wifi.

it doesn't give any error. (I am entering right password).

I selected the gear icon next to my network and I can see that its using WPA & WPA2 Personal and it has the right password. Everything else is set to automatic.

I am using this wifi card

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIABG954D3777

Edit: I formatted the hard drive and installed windows 10. and windows 10 connected to wifi without any problem. So clearly Ubuntu has a problem with the PCI wifi card.

Comment: which wifi card are you using?

Comment: Maybe the card isn't fully supported, or needs some tweaking. Try a USB wifi adapter, at least to verify the software & settings & password work

Comment: added the link to wifi card.

Comment: Can you open up a terminal, type in `dmesg` and see what your driver's telling you? Also give us the output of `sudo lshw -class network`, this will tell us how the kernel sees your network card

Comment: I forgot `lspci`, your network adapter should also appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the network manager service.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Also, I know it's a longshot and you said otherwise, but `cd` to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` check the relevant file of your wifi connection to see whether the saved wifi password is different than the one you are entering.

Comment: did not solve the problem. It is still getting stuck at connecting....